# How to render the CloseIcon only when the image is inserted?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a form similar to google forms. Whenever a user inserts image I want to preview the image. Now, I have created a function updateImageLink to update the state once user inserts image. The function is below:

```
updateImageLink = (link, position) => {
   let questions = [...this.state.questions];
   let i = position.question;

   if (position.option == null) {
      questions[i].questionImage = link;
   } else {
      var j = position.option
      questions[i].options[j].optionImage = link;
   }

   this.setState({ questions });
}
```

Suppose the user wants to delete the image so for that I have created a delete button and passed the function through `onClick` prop as follows:

```
<IconButton
   style={{
      marginLeft: "3px",
      marginTop: "-15px",
      zIndex: 999,
      backgroundColor: "lightgrey",
      color: "grey",
   }}
   size="small"
   onClick={() => {
      this.updateImageLink("", { question: i, option: null });
   }}
>
   <CloseIcon />
</IconButton>
```

Now, this code renders the `CloseIcon` even when there's no image. The problem is with binding the function. If I write:

```
onClick={this.updateImageLink("", { question: i, option: null })}
```

Then `CloseIcon` does not render and the state does not get updated as well.

---

The state of class is as follows:

```
this.state = {
            questions: [
                {
                    questionText: "Question 1",
                    questionImage:null,
                    options: [
                        { optionText: "Option 1",
                          optionImage: null },
                        { optionText: "Option 2",
                          optionImage: null },
                        { optionText: "Option 3",
                          optionImage: null },
                        { optionText: "Option 4",
                          optionImage: null }
                    ],
                    correctAnswer: ""
                }
            ],
            openUploadImagePop: false,
            imagePositionData: {
                question: null,
                option: null
            }
      }
```

So, how to render the `CloseIcon` only when the image is inserted?

Comment: can you provide link to repo or put your project on stackblitz ?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this question by updating the state as follows:

```
this.state = {
            questions: [
                {
                    questionText: "Question 1",
                    options: [
                        { optionText: "Option 1" },
                        { optionText: "Option 2" },
                        { optionText: "Option 3" },
                        { optionText: "Option 4" }
                    ],
                    correctAnswer: ""
                }
            ],
            openUploadImagePop: false,
            imagePositionData: {
                question: null,
                option: null
            }
        };
    }
```

Here as there's no `questionImage` or `optionImage` field the unnecessary `CloseIcon` rendering problem is solved. Whenever, image is uploaded `questionImage` or `optionImage` gets added in the state through updateImageLink function.